# How to count items in arrays of values in an array of hashes

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have an array of hashes that contain an array of items as the hash value. Here's the structure:

```
arr = [
  {:title => "String1", :link => ["URL1", "URL2"]},
  {:title => "String2", :link => ["URL3", "URL4", "URL5"]}
]
```

I'd like to add a key-value pair that counts the items in each `:link` like this:

```
arr = [
  {:title => "String1", :link => ["URL1", "URL2"], :link_count => 2},
  {:title => "String2", :link => ["URL3", "URL4", "URL5"]}, :link_count => 3 
]
```

I can get to the counts of each `:link` using this:

```
arr.map{|x| x[:link].count}
```

but I can't persist the count as a new key. Any ideas?

Comment: Your expected array is invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do it by `Array#each` as below,

```
> arr.each { |h| h[:link_count] = h[:link].count }
# => [{:title=>"String1", :link=>["URL1", "URL2"], :link_count=>2}, {:title=>"String2", :link=>["URL3", "URL4", "URL5"], :link_count=>3}]
```

Comment: This is by far the most straightforward method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [merge!](https://apidock.com/ruby/Hash/merge!) method which alter the original array with the new changes.

```
arr.map { |x| x.merge!({ link_count: x[:link].count }) }
```